# How to burn mp3 files to an audio CD under Scientific-Linux 6.1?

Tags: audio, scientific-linux, mp3

It should be an easy thing.. but a strange thing happened when I tried in Brasero:

"XXX.mpg is not suitable for audio or video media"

[image]

I had the same problem with K3B.
What package did I forget to install? What should I do to burn MP3 files to an audio CD?

Comment: What program were you using, that produced this dialog box? Under which distribution?

Comment: Brasero, but K3b also complains about mp3 files :O

Comment: So IMHO it's not strictly a brasero-2.28.3-6.el6.x86_64 related problem.. some codec could be missing, but can't figure it out which one.. :\

Comment: in here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1317378 it was solved by installing the libk3b6-extracodecs package, but it's not in the sl repos

Comment: yum install gstreamer-plugins-ugly.x86_64 solved it..

Comment: I think you (gasko peter) is supposed to make that an answer and then accept it .. that way the question is no longer unanswered ;)

Comment: because of the stackexchange rules, I couldn't answer my question. Now I could posted it as an answer, but now I can't accept it as an answer.. waiting for tomorrow to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yum install gstreamer-plugins-ugly.x86_64
```

solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're going to have to install the k3b extracodecs from the RPM Fusion Repos.

Comment: I read on dr. google that that could be the answer too, but I didn't had the "extracodecs" package in my offical repos.